# I have a problem with bootstrap mediaquery

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I created a simple carousel with Bootstrap.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    bottom: 130px !important;
  }
  .carousel-caption p {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    bottom: 125px !important;
  }
  .carousel-caption h5 {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .carousel-caption a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .carousel-caption p {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.6px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-caption h5 {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.9;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="img/pexels-binyamin-mellish-186077.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 1">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h5>Second slide label</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3">Learn More</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I then assigned the CSS properties.

[image]

**Carousel view in full screen**

[image]

**I reduced the height of the page.**

```
    .carousel-caption{
    bottom: 220px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

When I decrease the height in this code and shrink the page, text comes to the center of the carousel. But this time, the text is shifting up on the big screen. How can I get these texts in the middle of the screen on every screen?

Comment: bottom: 220px may be why despite the page height shrinking you are still saying caption should be 220px from the bottom

 can you swap to margin: auto? usually that will center it you may to assign a width to the h5 to get that margin to work

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask]. Then, provide more code in the snippet demo to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting bottom to some fixed px, make that div height same as parent height by setting top and bottom like following:

```
  .carousel-caption{
     top:0;
     display: flex;
     justify-content:center;
     align-items: center;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: 2;
  }
```

and we used flexbox here to center the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the regular CSS rules (without media conditions) at the bottom of your stylesheet, they will overwrite your media queries, since they follow after them and are valid for *every*  size.

So just change the order to avoid this: Move the regular rules to the top and let the media queries follow below them. Then the regular rules will be overwritten by the media queries (for the defined sizes) as desired.